# How to pass a cellfilter along with data in ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I have one situation I have to plot the table horizontally. The Data is dynamic.

```
Iteam 1
RowHeder1 : Value 1
RowHeder2 : Value 2
RowHeder3 : Value 3
RowHeder4 : Value 4
```

How can I create it? And is it possible to pass the cell filter along with data object?

```
$scope.gridOptions.data =[
{
"display": "RowHeder1 ",
"property":23.24,
"CellFilter": "MyFilter | $"
},
{
"display": "RowHeder2 ",
"property":"2nd June",
"CellFilter": "MyDateFilter | DD-MM-YY"
},
]
```

plunker [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2pjZqL3jgVSVQzYfg9JM?p=preview)
Thanks in Advance :)
Kiran Gopal

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible because `cellFilter` is a property of the `columnDef` and that cannot be changed.

However you can create a method/service where you can "process" your data and then pass it to the grid. Based on your data you can create the `columnDef` with the right `cellFilter` so the grid will work as expected.

If this is not clear enough please create a JSFiddle with your data and add a link as a comment.